# Retrieving and passing data to form input

Tags: php, laravel, variables, input

I have two DB tables as item and price.

In view file, `foreach` of items I have form element as

```
<input type="text" name="dc_{{$item->id}}" value="{{$price->dc_*}}">
```

I want * in value as `dc_{{$item->id}}` for an example like `dc_4` or `dc_7`

I am unable to use `{{ $price-> dc_{{$item->id}} }}` for value as it is wrong syntax.

What's an alternative way to implement such logic?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want in value? If you want dc_somecolumn you could just do same as in `name`: "dc_{{price->some_col}}"

Comment: Did you try ` {{ $'$price-> dc_'.$item->id }}`?

Comment: I suggest you make better db query or generate better response from controller. To avoid such complex situation to make good data binding b/w item and price.

Comment: Or just share your controller query ? We will help you make as you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<input type="text" name="dc_{{ $item->id }}" value="{{ $price->{ 'dc_' . $item->id } }}">
```

Comment: Yes this would fix the error. Do you have any idea to avoid this situation but keep same output?

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this syntax.